# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:. neither merge nor saveOrUpdate works

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a GUI where a list of teachers is shown. Two are selected by the user - they are going to be the form teachers of a new school class that gets created.
The teacher - class relationship is n-m.

School class: (it inherits its id from its group)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="school_classes")
@Cacheable(true)
public class SchoolClass extends Group{

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="classes", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private SortedSet<Teacher> teachers;
```

Teacher:

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="teachers")
    @Cacheable(true)
    public class Teacher extends creator.models.school.Entity{
            // name etc

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="class_teachers",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private SortedSet<SchoolClass> classes;
```

I try to create a new class like this:

```
String className = request.getParameter("class_name");
String id1 = request.getParameter("class_teacher1");
String id2  = request.getParameter("class_teacher2");
Teacher t1 = DataRetrieveModule.getTeacher(id1);
Teacher t2 = DataRetrieveModule.getTeacher(id2);


Layout l = new Layout();
SchoolClass newClass = new SchoolClass(className);
newClass.setLayout(l);
newClass.addTeacher(t1);
t1.addClass(newClass);

newClass.addTeacher(t2);
t2.addClass(newClass);
DataInsertionModule.insert(newClass);
```

This statement `DataRetrieveModule.getTeacher(id1)` opens a session, retrives the teacher by ID and closes it.
`DataInsertionModule.insert(newClass)` also opens a session, calls  `session.saveOrUpdate(newClass)`. (I also tried `session.merge(newClass)`)

Retrieving a teacher:

```
public static Teacher getTeacher(String id) {
        Session session = null;
        Teacher t = null;
        try{
            sessionFactory = MyFactory.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            t = (Teacher) session.get(Teacher.class, Long.parseLong(id));

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("in DAO:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }       
        finally{
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Data insertion:

```
public static void insert(Object o) {
        Session session = null;

        try 
        {
            sessionFactory = MyFactory.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(o);
            tx.commit();

            System.out.println("insertion done");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }
    }
```

But insertion never works.
There is always an object with the same id that already exists.

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [creator.models.school.Teacher#3]
```

I searched on stackoverflow and have overridden my getHashCode and equals method in the class all my business objects inherit from:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Entity o) {
    if(this.id < o.getId())
        return -1;
    else if(this.id > o.getId())
        return 1;
    return this.getClass().getName().compareTo(o.getClass().getName());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Entity)
        return this.compareTo((Entity)o)==0;
    else return this.equals(o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    char[] bla = this.getClass().getName().toCharArray();
    int blue=0;
    for(char c:bla)
        blue = blue*10 + c;
    return (int) (id+blue);

}
```

Furthermore I tried to change the `CascadeType` of `ManyToMany` to `MERGE` (reverted again).

At the moment I merge the teacher objects after retrieving both of them with session.get(..), as retrieving takes a lot of data out of the DB. There are futher  `..ToMany` relations. Therefore it probably might happen, that the call causes that both teachers are loaded.

```
public static Object merge(Object o) {
        Session session = null;
        Object returnVal = null;
        try 
        {
            sessionFactory = MyFactory.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            returnVal = session.merge(o);
            tx.commit();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(session!=null)
                session.close();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

.

```
Teacher t1 = DataRetrieveModule.getTeacher(id1);
Teacher t2 = DataRetrieveModule.getTeacher(id2);

t1= DataInsertionModule.merge(t1);
t2= DataInsertionModule.merge(t2);
```

Therefore I thought, that if I merge the one my get-method returned with the one that must have been loaded by the get call for the other teacher, it should work. (like here: http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/) But it does not :(

Is it probably because an object of the same superclass (Object or my Entity class) has the same ID?

Please help me!

Comment: try to override equals() and hashCode() methods on children classes directly,not parent, use id field as part of this methods.

Comment: show the methods of DataRetrieveModule please. "identity" in this context means the database identity, i.e. the primary key. So, the message means that you have two objects with different object identifiers (the java identifiers), but the same database identifier (primary key) associated with the same session. Since the state of the entity in question will depend on the order of which the two objects are stored, JPA does not allow this.

Comment: @Tobb I added the methods to the post. Do you mean by primary key a key regardless of the table it belongs to? Is the problem that I have a Student with id 1 and a Teacher with id 1? They share a superclass.

Answer (score 4):

One potential situation that could lead to this error is when the id of teacher 1 and teacher 2 is the same. Since you close the session between each get they will be detached, and you would end up loading two different objects that both represent the same row in the database (they have the same primary key.) Then, when these are both going to be reattached to a session through a SchoolClass being saved, Hibernate will see two different objects both representing the same row in the database, and not know which one represent the correct state to persist to the database.

Don't know for sure if this is the case here, but you should run a debugger and check the state of the objects referenced by teacher1 and teacher2.

Comment: no, the ones that I loaded directly are not identic. But it might be that, when loading the first one, the 2nd one is loaded already, because of eager loading and relations not shown in the code above. This is very likely though. But what can I do about it? Merging? I add the code on how I tried to merge duplicates to my initial post.

Comment: it is strange.. For testing I tried to merge every object I retrieve from the database upon getting it and to merge it again before updating it.. even that does not help..

Comment: You really should run a debugger, then you can look at the entire object graph that you are trying to persist. Btw, in your merge-method, should the catch clause contain `tx.rollback()`? I'm used to using container-based session/transaction management (spring), I think the problem here is closing the session between every call to the DataRetrieveModule. It should be something like this: 1. Open session, 2. Get objects, do stuff and save, 3. Close the session. Then, if you have try to load two objects with the same identifier, they will be the same object (loaded from session cache 2nd time).